# How to manage between more than two threads requesting from the server?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-multithreading, serversocket

THE SERVER SIDE:

```
def data():
      data2=""
        with open('group9.json') as file:
           readed_Data=json.load(file)
               
       for data in readed_Data['data']:
           data_send+=data
       return data2

def connected(sock,id):
    print("Thread starts",id)

    name= sock_a.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')        

    API=requests.get("https://api.agify.io/?name="+name)
    response=API.text
    data=json.loads(response)
    
    #To save the new info
    with open("temporary_file.json","w") as file:
          json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
    

    while True:
            #recieve number from client
            number = sock_a.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
       
            data_send=""
            if(number=="1"):
                 data_send=data()
            else:
                 data_send="not=1"
            sock.sendall(data_send.encode('utf-8'))

#TCP SOCKET
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock_p: 
sock_p.bind(("127.0.0.1", 49999))
#sock_p.settimeout(15)

sock_p.listen(3)
threads=[]
while True:
    sock_a, sockname = sock_p.accept()
    print("connected to ",sockname[0],sockname[1])
    t = threading.Thread(target=connected, args=(sock_a,len(threads)+1))
    threads.append(t)
    print(threads)
    t.start()
```

this is the code for the server-side {THREAD} the problem when two clients or more are requesting different names after the second time the client gets a block on the recv in the client side, i think the problem is from the threading is there any solution

THE CLIENT SIDE:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock_p: 

    sock_p.connect(("127.0.0.1", 49999))

 while True:
        
        print("enter the name")
        name=input()
        sock_p.sendall(name.encode('utf-8'))
        print("enter the number")
        number=input()
        sock_p.sendall(number.encode('utf-8'))
        data=sock_p.recv(1024)  
        print(data)
```

Comment: It's not really possible to say what is actually going on with the code provided – there are no threads, and the kind of sockets is not clear either. Please take a look at the [mcve] help page.

Comment: From what I can gather and making some assumptions, it looks like your protocol is inherently 1-to-1 – there is only one connection (``sock``) and it is used for recv-send/send-recv pairs. Once there are several clients 1 and 2, you can get interleaving recv1-recv2-send1-send2 "pairs" that the code does not handle.

Comment: i edit it take a look again please

Comment: Your server reads from *the global* ``sock_a``, not the client/thread/function local ``sock``. As soon as another client connects, all existing threads will switch to its socket.

Comment: TLDR: Use only ``sock`` instead of ``sock_a`` inside of ``connected``.